# Two inputs to map() but only iterate over one of them

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to write a function that iterates over a vector using `map2()`, but which also takes another input which is fixed on each call.

For example, this code takes just the one input, `vars`:

```
library(carData)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(Matching)

vars <- c("lfp", "lwg", "inc")
names(vars) <- vars

matching_fcn <- function(.x){
  
  matching_df <- Mroz %>% 
  mutate(wc = case_when(wc == "yes" ~ "TRUE", 
                        wc == "no" ~ "FALSE")) %>% 
  drop_na(k5, k618, age, wc, hc, .x)

matching_df$wc <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)
  ps1 <- glm(wc ~ k5 + k618 + age + hc, 
             family = binomial, data = matching_df)
  
  pscore <- ps1$fitted.values
  matching_df <- cbind(matching_df, pscore)
  
  Y <- matching_df[[.x]]
  Tr <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)
  
  psm1 <- Matching::Match(
    Y = Y, 
    Tr = Tr, 
    X = pscore, 
    estimand = "ATT", 
    M = 1, 
    replace = TRUE, 
    caliper = 0.05, 
    version = "fast")
  p <- 1 - pnorm(abs(psm1$est.noadj/psm1$se.standard))
  with(psm1, tibble(dv=.x, est=est.noadj, se=se.standard, p=p, ndrops=ndrops))
}

purrr::map_df(
  .x =  tidyselect::all_of(vars),
  .f = matching_fcn)
```

But if I want to run the same models on a different df which has the same variable names, i will need to copy the whole function again and change the line `matching_df <- ....` which is sub-optimal.

I tried to solve for this using `map2()` but it's returning an error that the dimensions of `.x` and `.y` are not the same (naturally) because it's attempting to iterate over `.y` as well as `.x`.

What I want is to be able to set up the function like this:

```
matching_fcn <- function(.x, .y){
  
  matching_df <- .y %>% ...
```

And call it like this:

```
purrr::map2_df(
  .x = tidyselect::all_of(vars),
  .y = df1,
  .f = matching_fcn)
```

or

```
purrr::map2_df(
  .x = tidyselect::all_of(vars),
  .y = df2,
  .f = matching_fcn)
```

Etc. Is this possible?

Comment: From the online doc for `map`:  "... Additional arguments passed on to the mapped function.".  So can't you simply pass `matching_df` (or its replacement) as an argument to `matching_fcn`?

Comment: Thanks Limey. That hasn't worked though. I've changed the function itself to be `matching_fcn <- function(.x, sample){
  Y <- {{sample}}[[.x]] .... }` And the call to be `purrr::map_dfr(
  .x = tidyselect::all_of(vars),
  .f = matching_fcn(sample = sample_imputed_1))` and it's returning this error: `Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, : argument ".x" is missing, with no default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly I don't think you should use `map2` here. As @Limey mentioned you can include data as argument in the function.

```
library(carData)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(Matching)

vars <- c("lfp", "lwg", "inc")
names(vars) <- vars

matching_fcn <- function(data, .x){
  
  matching_df <- data %>% 
    mutate(wc = case_when(wc == "yes" ~ "TRUE", 
                          wc == "no" ~ "FALSE")) %>% 
    drop_na(k5, k618, age, wc, hc, .x)
  
  matching_df$wc <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)
  ps1 <- glm(wc ~ k5 + k618 + age + hc, 
             family = binomial, data = matching_df)
  
  pscore <- ps1$fitted.values
  matching_df <- cbind(matching_df, pscore)
  
  Y <- matching_df[[.x]]
  Tr <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)
  
  psm1 <- Matching::Match(
    Y = Y, 
    Tr = Tr, 
    X = pscore, 
    estimand = "ATT", 
    M = 1, 
    replace = TRUE, 
    caliper = 0.05, 
    version = "fast")
  p <- 1 - pnorm(abs(psm1$est.noadj/psm1$se.standard))
  with(psm1, tibble(dv=.x, est=est.noadj, se=se.standard, p=p, ndrops=ndrops))
}
```

Call this as -

```
purrr::map_df(
  .x =  tidyselect::all_of(vars),
  .f = ~matching_fcn(Mroz, .x))

#  dv      est     se        p ndrops
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 lfp   0.175 0.0450 5.07e- 5      5
#2 lwg   0.375 0.0571 2.49e-11      5
#3 inc   4.84  1.09   4.82e- 6      5
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you